# Loop through JSON object, an array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an JSON object which is like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["records"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["Subject"]=>
      string(9) "algorithm"
      ["Object"]=>
      string(7) "program"
      ["Predicate"]=>
      string(3) "isa"
      ["Count"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["Source"]=>
      string(14) "Basic instinct"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["Subject"]=>
      string(18) "Amazing Pillow 2.0"
      ["Object"]=>
      string(3) "199"
      ["Predicate"]=>
      string(40) "The best pillow for amazing programmers."
      ["Count"]=>
      string(2) "-1"
      ["Source"]=>
      string(2) "in"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to push the Subject values of each array to a new array if Subject has the word "algorithm". I am writing the php code like that:

```
foreach($data as $row => $value) {
    foreach($value as $row2 => $value2){
        if(in_array("algorithm", $value2->Subject)) {
            array_push($result, $value2);
        }
    else { array_push($result, "no record");}
    }
}
```

But, it looks empty and I don't know why. If anyone can help, I'll be glad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would loop your array this way:

```
foreach($data['records'] as $record) {
  if($record["Subject"] == "algorithm")
    array_push($result, $record);
  else
    array_push($result, "no record");
}
```

Let me know if it's what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I need. I have an array of nouns(such as "algorithm") and I want to find the records that have one of these nouns inside.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is 3 level
so Or you  start for $data['records']  or use 3 level foreach

```
foreach($data['records'] as $row => $value) {
    foreach($value as $row2 => $value2){
        if(in_array("algorithm", $value2->Subject)) {
            array_push($result, $value2);
        }
    else { array_push($result, "no record");}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have used like $data['records'].

Answer (score 0):

$value2->Subject is not an array but a string. Hence in_array() doesn't match.

Does it work, if you simply inside your foreach-loop check 
if ($value2->Subject === "algorithm") 
?